# What kind of network functions/API is used in mobile apps(mobile network programming)?

Tags: android, sockets, mobile, network-programming

Do mobile devices also use network sockets? If so are they identical or different from the Berkeley sockets? Particularly for mobile IP.

Moreover, what is the API for the mobile GSM/CDMA protocols? In particular for Android phones.

Comment: I would say it depends on the operating system, languages and frameworks used.

Comment: Android is based on Linux, and uses a language and framework based on Java. So yes on sockets.